# Screenshot [ctypes.windll CreateDCFromHandle]

Tags: python, ctypes, python-mss

I am creating a screenshot module using only pure python (ctypes), no big lib like win32, wx, QT, ... It has to manage multi-screens (what PIL and Pillow cannot).

Where I am blocking is when calling CreateDCFromHandle, ctypes.windll.gdi32 does not know this function. I looked at win32 source code to being inspired, but useless. As said in comment, this function does not exist in the MSDN, so what changes should I apply to take in consideration other screens?

This is the code which works for the primary monitor, but not for others: [source code](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/blob/master/mss/windows.py).
It is blocking at the line 35. I tried a lot of combinations, looking for answers here and on others websites. But nothing functional for me ... It is just a screenshot!

Do you have clues?

Thanks in advance :)

---

Edit, I found my mystake! This is the code that works:

```
srcdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowDC(0)
memdc = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(srcdc)
bmp = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(memdc, bmp)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, width, height, srcdc, left, top, SRCCOPY)        
bmp_header = pack('LHHHH', calcsize('LHHHH'), width, height, 1, 24)
c_bmp_header = c_buffer(bmp_header) 
c_bits = c_buffer(' ' * (height * ((width * 3 + 3) & -4)))
got_bits = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(memdc, bmp, 0, height,
                        c_bits, c_bmp_header, DIB_RGB_COLORS)
# Here, got_bits should be equal to height to tell you all goes well.
```

French article with full explanations : [Windows : capture d'écran](http://www.tiger-222.fr/?d=2013/08/05/21/35/31-windows-capture-decran)

Comment: MSDN doesn't seem to know that function.

Comment: That is right, after all searches I did, this function is always present into code source -- but not into the MSDN. Where can I apply changes to take in consideration other screens?

Comment: Hm no, I do not use argtypes. This code works on Windows 7 64 bits.
Should I use argtypes if I do not declare functions?

Comment: Ah yes. It was python 32 bits on Windows 64 bits ... Just check'in. Thank you.

Comment: I tried and all works like a charm. Python 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3 in 64 bit version on Windows 7 64 bits => good.
Could you tell me exactly what line you would add/change please?

Comment: The original post has a link to source code that is not valid. Ideally I would have left this as a comment but as I don't have enough reputation I'm going to leave this here: you can find the source code at https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/blob/master/mss/windows.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, I found my mystake! This is the code that works:

```
srcdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowDC(0)
memdc = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(srcdc)
bmp = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(memdc, bmp)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, width, height, srcdc, left, top, SRCCOPY)        
bmp_header = pack('LHHHH', calcsize('LHHHH'), width, height, 1, 24)
c_bmp_header = c_buffer(bmp_header) 
c_bits = c_buffer(' ' * (height * ((width * 3 + 3) & -4)))
got_bits = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(
    memdc, bmp, 0, height, c_bits, c_bmp_header, DIB_RGB_COLORS)
# Here, got_bits should be equal to height to tell you all goes well.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/file/ed400a27739f/Pythonwin/win32dc.cpp#l138) for [`pywin32`](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/), `CreateDCFromHandle` is a fabrication. It does not exist in the Windows API; it is simply a bridge converting a Windows API thing into a `pywin32` thing.

Since you're using `ctypes` rather than `pywin32`, no conversion is necessary; see if you can skip that step:

```
hwin = user.GetDesktopWindow()
hwindc = user.GetWindowDC(monitor['hmon'])
memdc = gdi.CreateCompatibleDC(hwindc)
```

When you're trying to do some native-Windows API thing with `ctypes` in Python, I find it more helpful to look at existing C code which already uses the Windows API rather than using Python code that uses a wrapper around it.

Comment: Yes, I am visiting the MSDN since 5 days but the retranscription is not as good as wanted. I saw that this function is sensed give me a DC for all monitors: gdi32.CreateDCW('DISPLAY', 0, 0, 0)
But the result is the same: only the primary monitor is grabbed.
I will continue investigating.

Comment: @eryksun: Right, but that probably doesn't end up doing anything useful with the Windows API. It just wraps a Windows API handle in another object.

Comment: @eryksun: Yeah, I had already read that part of the code and saw that. I referenced it but didn't include it in my answer because I didn't think it was relevant. I will add a link to the source though, since that might be useful for anyone interested.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Windows API function. You will need a combination of [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CreateDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Be aware that you must append "A" or "W" to the names of the functions depending on if you want to use ANSI strings or Unicode (widechar) strings.

Comment: Yes, EnumDisplayDevices() returns coordinates, windows handles and DC handles. But these values (handles) does not work, perhaps I misunderstand how it works. CreateDCW('DISPLAY', 0, 0, 0) should create a DC for all monitors (as said in the MSDN), but retrieving pixels from the 2nd monitor does not work.

Comment: @Tiger-222 Then you should try to retrieve the pixels for each monitor separately

Comment: It is what I want :) It is working for the primary monitor, but not for the 2nd. All seems to work until GetDIBits() which does not return the désired value. Black picture.